# Three subplots in Python using the same data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm currently needing some help here since I’m kinda novice. So I was able to import and plot my time series data via Pandas and Matplotlib, respectively. The thing is, the plot is too cramped up (due to the amount of data lol).

Using the same data set, is it possible to ‘divide’ the whole plot into 3 separate subplots?

Here's a sample to what I mean:
[image]

What I'm trying to do here is to distribute my plot into 3 subplots (it seems it doesn't have `ncol=x`).

Initially, my code runs like this;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
data = pd.read_csv ('all_visuallc.csv')   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['JD', 'Magnitude'])
print(df) #displays ~37000ish data x 2 columns

colors = ('#696969') #a very nice dim grey heh
area = np.pi*1.7

ax = df.plot.scatter(x="JD", y="Magnitude", s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.2)
ax.set(title='HD 39801', xlabel='Julian Date', ylabel='Visual Magnitude')
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [20, 4]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 250
plt.savefig('test_p.jpg')
plt.show()
```

which shows a very tight plot:

[image]

Thanks everyone and I do hope for your help and responses.

*P.S. I think* `iloc[value:value]` *to slice from a df may work?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to create multiple plots for every part of your data.
For example, if we want to split data into 3 parts, we will create 3 subplots. And then, as you correctly wrote, we can apply *iloc* (or another type of indexing) to the data.

Here is a toy example, but I hope you are be able to apply your decorations to it.

```
y = np.arange(0,20,1)
x = np.arange(20,40,1)
sample = pd.DataFrame(x,y).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'y', 
0:'x'})

n_plots = 3
figs, axs = plt.subplots(n_plots, figsize=[30,10])
# Suppose we want to split data into equal parts
start_ind = 0
for i in range(n_plots):
    end_ind = start_ind + round(len(sample)/n_plots) #(*)
    part_of_frame = sample.iloc[start_ind:end_ind]
    axs[i].scatter(part_of_frame['x'], part_of_frame['y'])
    start_ind = end_ind
```

[image: Sample]

It's also possible to split data into unequal parts by changing the logic in the string (*)

Comment: I do apologize for the late response. Nonetheless, it actually works. :) I got a small concern tho. One of the subplots (the bottom part) only contains the starting and end points data. While the rest of the data occupies the 1st and 2nd subplot. https://prnt.sc/101tnjd

Comment: or I think it's because of the start and end_ind ^^

Comment: Thank you for finding a bug.
Please, test it now:)
I fixed the logic of finding indexes and the method of rounding. Now if the last part of frame is smaller than round(len(frame)/n_plots), it will be plotted correctly.

Comment: Alright. It finally worked <3 Thanks a lot :D

Comment: I am very glad to help you :)

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry if I have bothered you already. So this may be a very small issue (yet again hahaha) that I just recently saw. The data which was plot’d, big thanks to your code, were a little bit not ‘equal’. My guess is its because of the amount of varying data since the “tick frequencies” were slightly off/imbalance (this JDs are painful...). And so, we can adjust the axes and tick locators as well am I correct? https://prnt.sc/102e5vl

Comment: wait I send a different photo (I was testing different no. of subplots). I mean this one. https://prnt.sc/102mya9

Comment: Hello! You absolutely don't bother me. I didn't quite understand what do you want. As far as I understand, you want to adjust x_ticks, but in what manner? Could you draw it by hand?